# Strange memory leaks showing up in Instruments

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

[image: Leaks]

Every few weeks I check my application for memory leaks using instruments ( awesome tool, really ). As you can see in the screenshots there are a few memory leaks in it. I used to ignore these as I never really knew why they were there and they didn't seem to increase anyways.

They are created on launch and well.. thats all I know about them.
Anyone any ideas on how I can figure out what library or part of my code is causing these leaks?

-- thanks

Comment: Post some code you are using, we are not "Instruments".

Comment: if i knew what code was producing these leaks i would fix it, my app is 23.000 lines of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch the view to the Call Tree view, and check the Hide System Libraries and the Hide Missing Symbols options on the left side.

You should be able to see a stack trace showing your where in your code the leak originates from.

If nothing is shown then one of a few things is true:

- the leak isn't your fault and is in one of the system libraries
- the app isn't built with debug symbols

Ensure debug symbols are not being stripped out and try again.

If instruments still shows nothing, uncheck the Hide System Libraries box, make a note of where instruments says the leak is and report it to Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

one way is to read the backtraces from the extended detail view (cmd+e)

Comment: it says there is no stack trace available for this block

Comment: ok. when this happens to me, i verify that the object is built with debug symbols, and that instruments can find them (if they are in a separate file). sometimes i deduce the program is (or is not) mine based on what could be symbolicated (in the surrounding frames).

Comment: not sure, I had some leaks before I posted these, but it showed exactly what symbol, or objc method created them -- I'll check again